# Join mySQL tables and output JSON for Ionic 2 App

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to join two tables example below;

```
            demo_one
----------------------------------------
id |    name      | position |     phone
----------------------------------------
 1 |    Moby Dick | Whale    | 1-403-651-4000
 2 |    Jaws      | Shark    | 1-403-651-4000


            demo_two
---------------------------------------------------
id |    name             | type     |   cell
---------------------------------------------------
 1 |    Son of Moby Dick | Whale    | 1-403-651-4000
 2 |    Son of Jaws      | Shark    | 1-403-651-4000
```

and this is the json result I am looking for

```
{
"demo_one":[
    {"name":"Moby Dick", "position":"Whale", "phone":"1-403-651-4000"},
    {"name":"Jaws", "position":"Shark", "phone":"1-403-651-4000"}
],

"demo_two":[
    {"name":"Son of Moby Dick", "type":"Whale", "cell":"1-403-651-4000"},
    {"name":"Son of Jaws", "type":"Shark", "cell":"1-403-651-4000"}
]
}
```

I have seen some examples on stack overflow, but I require this json output for my Ionic 2 App.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a join. You're not connecting the rows in the two tables to each other.

Comment: It's just two separate queries, whose results are put into different properties in the JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't require a join, just two separate queries. Their results get put into different properties of the JSON result.

```
$result = array();
$query1 = $pdoconn->query("SELECT * FROM demo_one");
$result['demo_one'] = $query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$query2 = $pdoconn->query("SELECT * FROM demo_two");
$result['demo_two'] = $query2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It seems I was trying to over think the solution.